# XCode building a command line tool with ncurses

Tags: xcode, cocoa, command-line, ncurses, curses

Using ncurse to build an app that consumes keystrokes one at a time from the user to create the following feature.

When the user presses tab, his current line will try to auto complete.

Using getch(), I take each value and add it into a buffer to be consumed when the user presses enter.

After each keystroke the screen is refreshed and the buffer is redrawn to the screen.

Issue:
I'm having a lot of trouble consuming unicode characters this way. 
Example: "Nìco" is coming out "NÃ¬co"

Answer (score 0):

```
initscr();
cbreak();
noecho();
nonl();
move(0,0);
scrollok(stdscr, TRUE);
keypad(stdscr, TRUE);
while(TRUE){
    int value = getch();
    if( value == '\r' ){
        int x,y;
        getyx(stdscr,y,x);
        move(y, 0);
        /// add loop and push to buffer
        char values[1024] = {};

        winnstr(stdscr,values, 1024);
        move(y+1, 0);
        printw("buffer was %s", values);
        move(0,0);   
        //break;
    }
    else {
        addch(value);
    }
}
```